# Lottie error:"Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: 'Unable to parse composition'"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

When i tried to load gif to my project suddenly return me error:

```
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: 'Unable to parse composition'
```

Image for more information [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGzs8.jpg)

I want to insert gif to my project I tried to use Lottie and Json File

My code so far

```
<forms:AnimationView 
    x:Name="animationView" 
    Grid.Row="1"
    Animation="first.json" 
    Loop="false" 
    AutoPlay="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `xmlns:lottie="clr-namespace:Lottie.Forms;assembly=Lottie.Forms"` to your XAML head and use this component

```
 <lottie:AnimationView 
                x:Name="AnimationView" 
                Animation="first.json" 
                AutoPlay="True" Loop="true"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

and dont forget to init  `AnimationViewRenderer.Init();` on MainActivity and AppDelegate

Comment: i did it but same error. where must be first.json in assest folder or ?

Comment: @HristoIvanov the json files must be in Assets for android and Resources for iOS

Comment: Yes I did it [link](https://imgur.com/a/Z368Qtz) but same error

Comment: Ok Thanks Fix it Paste 'AnimationViewRenderer.Init()' at wrong place Thanks again for advice

Comment: @HristoIvanov Please try putting AnimationViewRenderer.Init(); below  base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

Answer (score 3):

My case: upgrade to latest version, because old Lottie does not support old json format

```
implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:6.0.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case i replaced `app:lottie_url` with `app:lottie_rawRes` , and it worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

need determine json like

Android: `DroidProject/Assets/filename.json` like AndroidAsset

iOS: `iOSProject/filename.json` like BundleResource

Comment: If this is meant to be an answer to the question at the top of this page then it needs [edit]ing to make the helpfully answering part more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred when `lottie.setAnimation("");` is not set or blank

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Lottie file was corrupted (I had mistakenly replaced some code in the source code of the Lottie file). I replaced a it with a correct Lottie file then it worked.